# How to use Elasticsearch bulk index with single JSON file in Python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch

I have a single JSON file formatted like:

```
    {"index":{"_type": "summary", "_id": "0001-1200-2015-12-31-0007", "_index": "transaction"}}
    {"data_load_user_id": "nathan", "tender_time": 5, "ring_time": 8, "operator_id": "0111"}
```

for about 12,000 rows. As far as I know, this is the correct way to format a JSON file for the bulk API in elasticsearch. I'm still confused on how to use es.bulk() with this single file as input. I already have the index and id specified for each row.

Comment: If you're using the official module check out `elasticsearch.helpers.bulk()`. I'm pretty sure you can pass a list containing your rows and it will do the right thing. Edit: here's the documentation: https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk

Comment: @Cfreak would it have to be a list of JSON objects or a list of strings? I tried opening the file and creating an iterator from it, but when I passed the iterator in, it gave the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'`

Comment: @Cfreak the documentation says "it consumes an iterator of actions and sends them to elasticsearch in chunks"; will the list count as an iterator?

Comment: True. It needs to be a `dict` (which gets converted back to JSON).

Comment: Yes. A list or an iterator will work. I'm digging through some of my code to see if I've ever done it straight from JSON instead of decoding and encoding back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah okay, so the `helpers.bulk()` module takes the list of dicts and my elasticsearch client as parameters and instead of having the 2 row per entry JSON file, I just needed to add the `"_index"` `"type"` and the `"_id"` to each JSON dict and it worked!